# Azure Active Directory Application per Country or Role per Country

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, rbac

I have a single application deployed several times to several countries which is secured using Azure Active Directory. I have a requirement that says, people should only have access to the application in their country. What is the best way to achieve this:

### Azure AD Application per Country

Create a new Azure AD application per country and use their respective client ID's in each country. This really increases the amount of config I have to deal with.

### Azure AD Roles per Country

I'm already using Role Based Access Security (RBAC). I could create a role for each country e.g. Kenya, then have the Kenya instance of the application require the Kenya role.

### Azure AD Multi-Tenanted Deployments

Each country is not a separate organization, it's all one company, so I'm not sure using Azure AD multi-tenant applies to my use case.

Comment: Does the application have the same URL? If so, you can check Traffic manager or other similar load/traffic balancer instead of Azure AD.

Comment: Each country has it's own URL.

Comment: Is this a Web App / Cloud service?

Comment: It's a Web App (API).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having multiple roles per country would probably be what I would go with. You can assign those country roles to AAD groups (if using a license that allows that), and through that also allow the future possibility of access to multiple instances. Of course if you are really sure that won't be necessary, then you can just assign users to the roles directly. The administrative workload is so much smaller that this is what I would go with. The only thing of course is that you will have to add all the reply URLs of all instances to the one app, instead of one in multiple apps.

One downside of the role-based approach is that it becomes a bit difficult to have other roles within the app, e.g. if you wanted to have a Kenya Admin role.

Creating an app per country seems slightly overkill, but it would have some advantages. Firstly, if needed, a user could be assigned to multiple apps to get access to multiple countries (and without paid licenses of AAD). App creation could be automated with a script. The main configuration you would have to have for each deployment would be the client id and secret. But a major downside is that if you need to e.g. add a permission to an API, you would have to add it to each app, and then consent it on each app.

Multi-tenant would mean that in addition to having different client ids and secrets, your users would have to be added to different Azure ADs. The isolation would be great, but this definitely incurs the highest amount of administrative work.

Comment: RBAC seems the simplest approach but how do I get around having to create new roles for every Azure AD application each time I need to create a new tenant?

Comment: So you have a tenant per country? Well, you can probably get around a lot of the work by using a PowerShell script or similar to add the roles. But yeah, that approach has the highest amount of work for administrating everything, it is simpler if you have everyone in one tenant.

Comment: I have one tenant per country or sometimes state in a country. Everything is PowerShell scripted at the moment using Azure AD's Basic subscription (Education company working in Africa). Only solution I can see is to write more PowerShell.

Comment: Hmm, if you made the app multi-tenanted I *think* the roles defined on the Application would become available for assignment in all the tenants. The problem of course is when you add a role later to the Application, it would not be propagated to the Service Principals in the other tenants without creating them again. Though that could be done with PS too. I don't know if that would actually make it easier though.